Uncompress tar.xz files with rust
I'm trying to uncompress a tar.xz file
I tried this code :
use xz::write::XzDecoder;
use tar::Archive;

fn main() {
    let file_output = "/path/to/my/file.tar.xz";

    let tar_gz = File::open(file_ouput).unwrap();
    let tar = XzDecoder::new(tar_gz);
    let mut archive = Archive::new(tar);
    archive.unpack(wine_dir).unwrap();
}

but I get this error :
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { kind: Other, error: TarError { desc: "failed to iterate over archive", io: Custom { kind: Other, error: "numeric field did not have utf-8 text: �^P��&�\u{3} when getting cksum for �7zXZ" } } }
one more info : the file I'm trying to uncompress is a file downloaded from internet

Have you reproduced the problem with a tar.xz file you created yourself? (If so, you should be able to include minimal steps to create such a file in the question, so folks can actually reproduce the behavior). And speaking of reproducibility, right now your code doesn't compile -- wine_dir is used but never defined.

Looking at the documentation for the xz crate, I think you should be using xz::read::XzDecoder rather than xz::write::XzDecoder because you want the decoder to read existing data from the file.

Oh my bad, after trying with a test project, the code works fine if I use xz::read::XzDecoder instead of xz::write::XzDecoder

After some looking, you get this error if you are using xz::write::XzDecoder, instead you have to use xz::read::XzDecoder like Francis said.
There is a code example :
use std::fs::File;
use tar::Archive;
use xz::read::XzDecoder;

fn main() {
    let file_input = "/path/to/compressed/file/test.tar.xz";
    let file_output = "/path/to/compressed/file";

    let tar_gz = File::open(file_input).unwrap();
    let tar = XzDecoder::new(tar_gz);
    let mut archive = Archive::new(tar);
    archive.unpack(file_output).unwrap();
}

